# Iterate array in [checked] condition

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I iterate `RoleIds` array to check conditions and check checkboxes where user role's Id is the same like role's Id from `role` array?

```
<md-accordion class="example-headers-align">
        <md-expansion-panel hideToggle="true" *ngFor="let u of userRole">
            <md-expansion-panel-header>
                <md-panel-title>
                    {{u.UserName}}
                </md-panel-title>
            </md-expansion-panel-header>
            <div *ngFor="let r of role; let i = index">
                <div>
                    <input type="checkbox" [checked]="(u.RoleIds[i] == r.Id) ? true : false">{{r.Name}}
                </div>
            </div>
            <md-action-row>
                <button md-button color="primary" (click)="saveChanges()">Approve</button>
            </md-action-row>
        </md-expansion-panel>
    </md-accordion>
```

Comment: Who does u (userRole) look like? maybe `(u.id === r.Id)` ? I have no clue..

Comment: userRole contain data of user (Id, name, age) and array of role's Id.

Comment: Maybe at an role to the user so (Id, name, age, role) then you can do `(u.role === r.Id)`